# How to prevent user from spamming aws services after he/she get AWS Service Policy from Cognito Identity Pool? (e.g. below)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, spam, ddos, aws-identitypools

- User signs up to User Pool.
- User signs in && get Token.
- Trade it for a policy in AWS Cog. Identity Pool. (e.g policy allows to query dynamodb table)
- User gerenate a script with tons of requests to the table OR user shares its credentials to fleet of hosts in order to spam a single dynamodb endpoint / table.

Can it be prevented?

Did not try anything.